# Extract numerical value from cut intervals

Tags: r, tidyverse, intervals

I'm trying to extract numbers from intervals (in this case the variable LONG) in one xmax and one xmin. Unfortunately when I'm trying to do that, the result is not correct and I do not get the digits. the intervals are set up with `cut`

my will is to do a ggplot graph with `geom_rect`, for that I need xmin and xmax

Here is a sample of my dataset

```
dput(head(df, n =200))
structure(list(Param = c("fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "par", "par", 
"par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "salinity", 
"salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
"salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "temperature", "temperature", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", 
"par", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
"salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "temperature", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "turbidity", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", 
"par", "par", "par", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
"salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
"fluorescence", "fluorescence", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", 
"par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
"salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
"salinity", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
"temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
"temperature", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
"turbidity"), ymin = c(220, 85, 0, 175, 25, 70, 225, 220, 100, 
70, 100, 85, 70, 25, 175, 0, 50, 180, 220, 225, 180, 0, 220, 
90, 25, 180, 100, 85, 50, 175, 25, 70, 90, 85, 85, 225, 180, 
0, 90, 85, 85, 180, 0, 0, 220, 180, 225, 90, 50, 25, 200, 50, 
50, 350, 220, 90, 0, 275, 25, 225, 350, 420, 480, 350, 225, 90, 
90, 70, 420, 90, 0, 100, 290, 180, 85, 400, 85, 90, 70, 200, 
50, 90, 300, 0, 180, 400, 90, 90, 200, 275, 200, 175, 70, 175, 
100, 300, 90, 220, 50, 290, 70, 290, 200, 200, 85, 100, 100, 
90, 25, 180, 290, 25, 400, 220, 200, 50, 0, 25, 275, 480, 400, 
300, 220, 0, 300, 220, 175, 100, 275, 180, 50, 400, 0, 0, 420, 
180, 290, 290, 90, 50, 275, 220, 275, 180, 290, 100, 175, 50, 
25, 225, 0, 85, 85, 100, 100, 175, 85, 180, 275, 90, 70, 275, 
90, 85, 90, 175, 180, 200, 85, 180, 50, 85, 350, 180, 50, 200, 
0, 90, 25, 90, 50, 50, 180, 200, 90, 220, 50, 90, 25, 85, 200, 
90, 70, 0, 90, 180, 50, 50, 70, 0), ymax = c(225, 90, 25, 180, 
50, 85, 275, 225, 175, 85, 175, 90, 85, 50, 180, 25, 70, 200, 
225, 275, 200, 25, 225, 100, 50, 200, 175, 90, 70, 180, 50, 85, 
100, 90, 90, 275, 200, 25, 100, 90, 90, 200, 25, 25, 225, 200, 
275, 100, 70, 50, 220, 70, 70, 400, 225, 100, 25, 290, 50, 275, 
400, 450, 500, 400, 275, 100, 100, 85, 450, 100, 25, 175, 300, 
200, 90, 420, 90, 100, 85, 220, 70, 100, 350, 25, 200, 420, 100, 
100, 220, 290, 220, 180, 85, 180, 175, 350, 100, 225, 70, 300, 
85, 300, 220, 220, 90, 175, 175, 100, 50, 200, 300, 50, 420, 
225, 220, 70, 25, 50, 290, 500, 420, 350, 225, 25, 350, 225, 
180, 175, 290, 200, 70, 420, 25, 25, 450, 200, 300, 300, 100, 
70, 290, 225, 290, 200, 300, 175, 180, 70, 50, 275, 25, 90, 90, 
175, 175, 180, 90, 200, 290, 100, 85, 290, 100, 90, 100, 180, 
200, 220, 90, 200, 70, 90, 400, 200, 70, 220, 25, 100, 50, 100, 
70, 70, 200, 220, 100, 225, 70, 100, 50, 90, 220, 100, 85, 25, 
100, 200, 70, 70, 85, 25), LONG = c(-23.99908333, -24.38488333, 
-23.07351667, -23.99908333, -24.9915, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, 
-24.9915, -23.99908333, -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -23.07351667, 
-23.07351667, -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, 
-25.15166667, -24.9915, -24.9915, -25.15166667, -24.9915, -23.99908333, 
-25.15166667, -23.07351667, -24.38488333, -25.15166667, -24.38488333, 
-24.9915, -24.38488333, -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -24.9915, 
-24.9915, -25.15166667, -24.9915, -23.99908333, -23.99908333, 
-25.15166667, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, -25.15166667, -23.07351667, 
-25.15166667, -23.99908333, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, -24.38488333, 
-24.38488333, -23.99908333, -26.1858, -26.1858, -19.79766667, 
-25.8803, -21.292, -26.1858, -19.79766667, -24.84261667, -22.91008333, 
-22.91008333, -22.91008333, -24.84261667, -24.84261667, -24.84261667, 
-19.79766667, -24.84261667, -26.1858, -19.79766667, -26.1858, 
-18.79291667, -19.79766667, -21.292, -25.8803, -25.8803, -25.8803, 
-25.8803, -26.1858, -25.8803, -18.79291667, -26.1858, -19.79766667, 
-21.292, -21.292, -26.1858, -26.1858, -25.8803, -18.79291667, 
-25.8803, -26.1858, -26.1858, -21.292, -24.84261667, -25.8803, 
-22.91008333, -25.8803, -24.84261667, -25.8803, -22.91008333, 
-21.292, -25.8803, -25.79463333, -24.36675, -26.3169, -25.79463333, 
-27.45433333, -27.45433333, -27.34373333, -27.34373333, -27.45433333, 
-26.3169, -24.36675, -24.68571667, -24.36675, -25.79463333, -26.3169, 
-27.34373333, -21.74423333, -24.36675, -25.79463333, -25.79463333, 
-24.36675, -25.79463333, -25.79463333, -21.74423333, -26.3169, 
-24.36675, -27.45433333, -24.68571667, -26.3169, -21.74423333, 
-27.45433333, -26.3169, -27.45433333, -24.36675, -25.79463333, 
-25.79463333, -21.74423333, -25.79463333, -26.3169, -27.34373333, 
-25.79463333, -26.3169, -26.3169, -21.74423333, -24.68571667, 
-21.74423333, -25.79463333, -24.36675, -25.79463333, -24.36675, 
-24.23426667, -24.23426667, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -22.3131, 
-23.79151667, -23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, -24.23426667, 
-22.3131, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -24.23426667, -24.23426667, 
-22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -22.3131, 
-23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, 
-23.79151667, -22.3131, -24.23426667, -23.79151667, -22.3131, 
-23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.50893333, -23.79151667, 
-22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.50893333, 
-23.79151667, -23.79151667, -23.79151667, -24.23426667, -23.79151667, 
-24.23426667), Transect = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    Value = c(0.08155852, 0.301815, 2.11627123809524, 0.08916896, 
    0.507806576576577, 0.376436462585034, 0.0796680773480663, 
    0.1813794, 0.116901057486631, 0.1968154, 2627.6870493992, 
    2627.7, 2627.70733333333, 2627.1951754386, 2627.7, 2627.56344086021, 
    2627.68923076923, 2627.69066666667, 2627.68, 2627.628, 34.5028693333333, 
    30.9015205882353, 34.624076, 33.471937, 34.0278530701754, 
    34.41674, 34.2245157543391, 33.1686533333333, 32.0401374358974, 
    34.3630434782609, 0.373296035242291, -1.09827823129252, -0.0840888888888889, 
    -0.0634604166666667, -0.414382, 0.19323, 0.3229585, 3.32400091743119, 
    -0.264504, -1.16256888888889, 0.49808, 301.2888, 0.546442857142857, 
    0.162839130434783, 1.81076, 2.19845, 1.6837679558011, 1.26615306122449, 
    0.814464646464646, 0.501614406779661, 0.059190285, 0.177087824120603, 
    0.665356180904523, 0.058553848, 0.07536708, 0.0737848, 1.16467572093023, 
    0.0630026533333333, 0.23709368, 0.067377656626506, 2627.74427244582, 
    2627.99566666667, 2628, 2628.0024, 2627.51050955414, 2628.2, 
    2628.2, 2627.50939597315, 2628.02584269663, 2627.9, 31.7818344186046, 
    34.4198116778524, 34.850228, 34.515901, 33.271, 34.8825898876404, 
    33.171312, 33.424846, 34.8067797297297, 34.5658145, -1.15515929648241, 
    -1.100712, 1.03213333333333, -0.217482105263158, 0.52464, 
    1.16056777777778, 2.24784, -1.114498, 0.7014795, 1.34177866666667, 
    1.016445, 0.45492, 0.467193333333333, 0.52288, 0.478332, 
    0.443222, 0.48876, 0.64078, 0.5768391959799, 0.46814, 0.0939222266666667, 
    0.06841773, 0.061016615, 0.06290749, 0.09016486, 0.0804777333333333, 
    0.125759906666667, 0.1289748, 0.174537983870968, 0.06137775, 
    2304.45894736842, 2231.32943548387, 2307.9145, 2289.804, 
    2295.2175, 2246.1025, 2265.73160377358, 2234.63024193548, 
    2293.86344827586, 2296.96853932584, 34.8405795, 34.6621464, 
    34.622442, 31.0418495283019, 34.65429, 34.74115, 34.504436, 
    34.2193344, 34.640094, 34.7676935, -0.0138485, 1.1815845, 
    -0.0814205240174673, 0.0226313043478261, 1.02302666666667, 
    0.5469705, 1.459401, 0.738181, -0.086665, -0.79061, 0.522664429530201, 
    0.56066, 0.555146666666667, 0.451445, 0.519727272727273, 
    0.435349397590361, 0.51554, 0.563185, 0.635352226720648, 
    0.566462, 0.751869561403509, 0.10155436, 0.0923774, 0.0732783297730307, 
    0.0726548930481283, 0.06541158, 0.08988464, 0.067170565, 
    0.0659365637583893, 0.106267666666667, 2248.35, 2306.9744966443, 
    2262.43608247423, 2236.832, 2228.29074074074, 2299.292, 2300.9735, 
    2303.06256410256, 2257.012, 2298.51875, 32.469601025641, 
    33.493826, 34.8967571428571, 34.7009225, 32.3693575, 34.7672785, 
    30.031902764977, 33.642694, 31.9030281512605, 33.6745559322034, 
    -1.635342, -1.62691897435897, 1.312134375, 1.420105, -1.28701, 
    1.50606, -0.82618, -1.200252, -1.57529705882353, -1.401896, 
    0.52944, 0.53251, 0.548925675675676, 2.22144104803493, 0.73419, 
    0.7245, 0.641565, 18.004535, 0.710006666666667, 3.60904385964912
    )), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here is the code

```
 #set up intervals 
require(tidyverse)
require(dplyr)
setx <- c(-27.75000,-27.45433,-27.34373,-26.37667,-26.31690,-26.18580,-25.88030,-25.81823,-25.79463,-25.15167,-24.99150,-24.84262,-24.68572,-24.38488,-24.36675,-24.23427,-24.01542,-23.99908,-23.79152,-23.07352,-22.91008,-22.50893,-22.31310,-21.74423,-21.29200,-19.79767)
df %>% 
  mutate(cut = cut(LONG, breaks =  setx)) %>% extract(cut, c("xmin", "xmax"), "(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)") %>% mutate(xmin = as.numeric(ymin)) %>% mutate(ymax = as.numeric(ymax))
```

For the ymax & ymin there was no problem doing that, but I suppose in that case it's because there is digits.

Comment: In official [document](http://127.0.0.1:18961/library/base/html/cut.html) of  the `cut` function you can see how to extract the values of bins with regex which is explained at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: There's a missing `,` in `setx` after the term `-25.81823`

Comment: @Desmond my bad, I have corrected it.

Comment: @maydin thank you I will check that tonight

Comment: @C.Guffens By the way, here is the  [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut) .  I think I sent a wrong link mistakenly.

Comment: @maydin, Thank you. The code propose in the link works but I didn't succeed to integrate it in the dataframe. I found another way with `df %>% extract(cut, c("xstart", "xend"), ".(.+),(.+).")` which permit to keep the upper and lower values in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the output you require?
If not, please provide a minimal example of how you wanted `xmin` and `xmax` to be.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dput(head(df, n =200))
#> structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
#> "    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)", 
#> "    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), .Dim = c(6L, 
#> 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")
df <- structure(list(Param = c("fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "par", "par", 
                         "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "salinity", 
                         "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
                         "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", 
                         "par", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
                         "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", 
                         "par", "par", "par", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
                         "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "fluorescence", 
                         "fluorescence", "fluorescence", "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", 
                         "par", "par", "par", "par", "par", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
                         "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", "salinity", 
                         "salinity", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", "temperature", 
                         "temperature", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
                         "turbidity"), ymin = c(220, 85, 0, 175, 25, 70, 225, 220, 100, 
                                                70, 100, 85, 70, 25, 175, 0, 50, 180, 220, 225, 180, 0, 220, 
                                                90, 25, 180, 100, 85, 50, 175, 25, 70, 90, 85, 85, 225, 180, 
                                                0, 90, 85, 85, 180, 0, 0, 220, 180, 225, 90, 50, 25, 200, 50, 
                                                50, 350, 220, 90, 0, 275, 25, 225, 350, 420, 480, 350, 225, 90, 
                                                90, 70, 420, 90, 0, 100, 290, 180, 85, 400, 85, 90, 70, 200, 
                                                50, 90, 300, 0, 180, 400, 90, 90, 200, 275, 200, 175, 70, 175, 
                                                100, 300, 90, 220, 50, 290, 70, 290, 200, 200, 85, 100, 100, 
                                                90, 25, 180, 290, 25, 400, 220, 200, 50, 0, 25, 275, 480, 400, 
                                                300, 220, 0, 300, 220, 175, 100, 275, 180, 50, 400, 0, 0, 420, 
                                                180, 290, 290, 90, 50, 275, 220, 275, 180, 290, 100, 175, 50, 
                                                25, 225, 0, 85, 85, 100, 100, 175, 85, 180, 275, 90, 70, 275, 
                                                90, 85, 90, 175, 180, 200, 85, 180, 50, 85, 350, 180, 50, 200, 
                                                0, 90, 25, 90, 50, 50, 180, 200, 90, 220, 50, 90, 25, 85, 200, 
                                                90, 70, 0, 90, 180, 50, 50, 70, 0), ymax = c(225, 90, 25, 180, 
                                                                                             50, 85, 275, 225, 175, 85, 175, 90, 85, 50, 180, 25, 70, 200, 
                                                                                             225, 275, 200, 25, 225, 100, 50, 200, 175, 90, 70, 180, 50, 85, 
                                                                                             100, 90, 90, 275, 200, 25, 100, 90, 90, 200, 25, 25, 225, 200, 
                                                                                             275, 100, 70, 50, 220, 70, 70, 400, 225, 100, 25, 290, 50, 275, 
                                                                                             400, 450, 500, 400, 275, 100, 100, 85, 450, 100, 25, 175, 300, 
                                                                                             200, 90, 420, 90, 100, 85, 220, 70, 100, 350, 25, 200, 420, 100, 
                                                                                             100, 220, 290, 220, 180, 85, 180, 175, 350, 100, 225, 70, 300, 
                                                                                             85, 300, 220, 220, 90, 175, 175, 100, 50, 200, 300, 50, 420, 
                                                                                             225, 220, 70, 25, 50, 290, 500, 420, 350, 225, 25, 350, 225, 
                                                                                             180, 175, 290, 200, 70, 420, 25, 25, 450, 200, 300, 300, 100, 
                                                                                             70, 290, 225, 290, 200, 300, 175, 180, 70, 50, 275, 25, 90, 90, 
                                                                                             175, 175, 180, 90, 200, 290, 100, 85, 290, 100, 90, 100, 180, 
                                                                                             200, 220, 90, 200, 70, 90, 400, 200, 70, 220, 25, 100, 50, 100, 
                                                                                             70, 70, 200, 220, 100, 225, 70, 100, 50, 90, 220, 100, 85, 25, 
                                                                                             100, 200, 70, 70, 85, 25), LONG = c(-23.99908333, -24.38488333, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -24.9915, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.9915, -23.99908333, -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -23.07351667, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.07351667, -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.15166667, -24.9915, -24.9915, -25.15166667, -24.9915, -23.99908333, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.15166667, -23.07351667, -24.38488333, -25.15166667, -24.38488333, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.9915, -24.38488333, -23.07351667, -23.99908333, -24.9915, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.9915, -25.15166667, -24.9915, -23.99908333, -23.99908333, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.15166667, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, -25.15166667, -23.07351667, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.15166667, -23.99908333, -24.38488333, -23.99908333, -24.38488333, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.38488333, -23.99908333, -26.1858, -26.1858, -19.79766667, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.8803, -21.292, -26.1858, -19.79766667, -24.84261667, -22.91008333, 
                                                                                                                                 -22.91008333, -22.91008333, -24.84261667, -24.84261667, -24.84261667, 
                                                                                                                                 -19.79766667, -24.84261667, -26.1858, -19.79766667, -26.1858, 
                                                                                                                                 -18.79291667, -19.79766667, -21.292, -25.8803, -25.8803, -25.8803, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.8803, -26.1858, -25.8803, -18.79291667, -26.1858, -19.79766667, 
                                                                                                                                 -21.292, -21.292, -26.1858, -26.1858, -25.8803, -18.79291667, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.8803, -26.1858, -26.1858, -21.292, -24.84261667, -25.8803, 
                                                                                                                                 -22.91008333, -25.8803, -24.84261667, -25.8803, -22.91008333, 
                                                                                                                                 -21.292, -25.8803, -25.79463333, -24.36675, -26.3169, -25.79463333, 
                                                                                                                                 -27.45433333, -27.45433333, -27.34373333, -27.34373333, -27.45433333, 
                                                                                                                                 -26.3169, -24.36675, -24.68571667, -24.36675, -25.79463333, -26.3169, 
                                                                                                                                 -27.34373333, -21.74423333, -24.36675, -25.79463333, -25.79463333, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.36675, -25.79463333, -25.79463333, -21.74423333, -26.3169, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.36675, -27.45433333, -24.68571667, -26.3169, -21.74423333, 
                                                                                                                                 -27.45433333, -26.3169, -27.45433333, -24.36675, -25.79463333, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.79463333, -21.74423333, -25.79463333, -26.3169, -27.34373333, 
                                                                                                                                 -25.79463333, -26.3169, -26.3169, -21.74423333, -24.68571667, 
                                                                                                                                 -21.74423333, -25.79463333, -24.36675, -25.79463333, -24.36675, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.23426667, -24.23426667, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -22.3131, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.79151667, -23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, -24.23426667, 
                                                                                                                                 -22.3131, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -24.23426667, -24.23426667, 
                                                                                                                                 -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -22.3131, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, -23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.79151667, -22.3131, -24.23426667, -23.79151667, -22.3131, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.79151667, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.50893333, -23.79151667, 
                                                                                                                                 -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.3131, -22.50893333, 
                                                                                                                                 -23.79151667, -23.79151667, -23.79151667, -24.23426667, -23.79151667, 
                                                                                                                                 -24.23426667), Transect = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                             4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                             4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                             4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
               Value = c(0.08155852, 0.301815, 2.11627123809524, 0.08916896, 
                         0.507806576576577, 0.376436462585034, 0.0796680773480663, 
                         0.1813794, 0.116901057486631, 0.1968154, 2627.6870493992, 
                         2627.7, 2627.70733333333, 2627.1951754386, 2627.7, 2627.56344086021, 
                         2627.68923076923, 2627.69066666667, 2627.68, 2627.628, 34.5028693333333, 
                         30.9015205882353, 34.624076, 33.471937, 34.0278530701754, 
                         34.41674, 34.2245157543391, 33.1686533333333, 32.0401374358974, 
                         34.3630434782609, 0.373296035242291, -1.09827823129252, -0.0840888888888889, 
                         -0.0634604166666667, -0.414382, 0.19323, 0.3229585, 3.32400091743119, 
                         -0.264504, -1.16256888888889, 0.49808, 301.2888, 0.546442857142857, 
                         0.162839130434783, 1.81076, 2.19845, 1.6837679558011, 1.26615306122449, 
                         0.814464646464646, 0.501614406779661, 0.059190285, 0.177087824120603, 
                         0.665356180904523, 0.058553848, 0.07536708, 0.0737848, 1.16467572093023, 
                         0.0630026533333333, 0.23709368, 0.067377656626506, 2627.74427244582, 
                         2627.99566666667, 2628, 2628.0024, 2627.51050955414, 2628.2, 
                         2628.2, 2627.50939597315, 2628.02584269663, 2627.9, 31.7818344186046, 
                         34.4198116778524, 34.850228, 34.515901, 33.271, 34.8825898876404, 
                         33.171312, 33.424846, 34.8067797297297, 34.5658145, -1.15515929648241, 
                         -1.100712, 1.03213333333333, -0.217482105263158, 0.52464, 
                         1.16056777777778, 2.24784, -1.114498, 0.7014795, 1.34177866666667, 
                         1.016445, 0.45492, 0.467193333333333, 0.52288, 0.478332, 
                         0.443222, 0.48876, 0.64078, 0.5768391959799, 0.46814, 0.0939222266666667, 
                         0.06841773, 0.061016615, 0.06290749, 0.09016486, 0.0804777333333333, 
                         0.125759906666667, 0.1289748, 0.174537983870968, 0.06137775, 
                         2304.45894736842, 2231.32943548387, 2307.9145, 2289.804, 
                         2295.2175, 2246.1025, 2265.73160377358, 2234.63024193548, 
                         2293.86344827586, 2296.96853932584, 34.8405795, 34.6621464, 
                         34.622442, 31.0418495283019, 34.65429, 34.74115, 34.504436, 
                         34.2193344, 34.640094, 34.7676935, -0.0138485, 1.1815845, 
                         -0.0814205240174673, 0.0226313043478261, 1.02302666666667, 
                         0.5469705, 1.459401, 0.738181, -0.086665, -0.79061, 0.522664429530201, 
                         0.56066, 0.555146666666667, 0.451445, 0.519727272727273, 
                         0.435349397590361, 0.51554, 0.563185, 0.635352226720648, 
                         0.566462, 0.751869561403509, 0.10155436, 0.0923774, 0.0732783297730307, 
                         0.0726548930481283, 0.06541158, 0.08988464, 0.067170565, 
                         0.0659365637583893, 0.106267666666667, 2248.35, 2306.9744966443, 
                         2262.43608247423, 2236.832, 2228.29074074074, 2299.292, 2300.9735, 
                         2303.06256410256, 2257.012, 2298.51875, 32.469601025641, 
                         33.493826, 34.8967571428571, 34.7009225, 32.3693575, 34.7672785, 
                         30.031902764977, 33.642694, 31.9030281512605, 33.6745559322034, 
                         -1.635342, -1.62691897435897, 1.312134375, 1.420105, -1.28701, 
                         1.50606, -0.82618, -1.200252, -1.57529705882353, -1.401896, 
                         0.52944, 0.53251, 0.548925675675676, 2.22144104803493, 0.73419, 
                         0.7245, 0.641565, 18.004535, 0.710006666666667, 3.60904385964912
               )), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                       "data.frame"))

setx <- c(-27.75000,-27.45433,-27.34373,-26.37667,-26.31690,-26.18580,-25.88030,-25.81823,-25.79463,-25.15167,-24.99150,-24.84262,-24.68572,-24.38488,-24.36675,-24.23427,-24.01542,-23.99908,-23.79152,-23.07352,-22.91008,-22.50893,-22.31310,-21.74423,-21.29200,-19.79767)

df %>%
  mutate(cut = cut(LONG, breaks =  setx)) %>%
  extract(cut,
          c("xmin", "xmax"),
          "(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)",
          remove = FALSE,
          convert = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 200 × 9
#>    Param         ymin  ymax  LONG Transect  Value cut              xmin  xmax
#>    <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>  <dbl> <fct>           <int> <int>
#>  1 fluorescence   220   225 -24.0        1 0.0816 (-24.02,-24]        2   -24
#>  2 fluorescence    85    90 -24.4        1 0.302  (-24.69,-24.38]    69   -24
#>  3 fluorescence     0    25 -23.1        1 2.12   (-23.07,-22.91]     7   -22
#>  4 fluorescence   175   180 -24.0        1 0.0892 (-24.02,-24]        2   -24
#>  5 fluorescence    25    50 -25.0        1 0.508  (-25.15,-24.99]    15   -24
#>  6 fluorescence    70    85 -24.4        1 0.376  (-24.69,-24.38]    69   -24
#>  7 fluorescence   225   275 -24.0        1 0.0797 (-24.02,-24]        2   -24
#>  8 fluorescence   220   225 -25.0        1 0.181  (-25.15,-24.99]    15   -24
#>  9 fluorescence   100   175 -24.0        1 0.117  (-24.02,-24]        2   -24
#> 10 fluorescence    70    85 -23.1        1 0.197  (-23.07,-22.91]     7   -22
#> # … with 190 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do the trick:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

df2 <- df %>% 
       mutate(cut = cut(LONG, breaks =  setx)) %>% 
       group_by(cut) %>%
       mutate(xmin   = min(LONG))  %>%
       mutate(xmax   = max(LONG))

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data=df2, aes(ymin=ymin,
                          ymax=ymax, 
                          xmin=xmin,  
                          xmax=xmax, 
                          color=cut,
                          fill=cut))
```

[image]